# Error in deleting a node in circular linked list

Tags: python, list, linked-list

Here is the code to delete the node in circular linked list:

```
def delete_node(head, value):
    p=head
    if p is None:
        return None
    while p.value != value:
        p = p.next
        if p.next is head and p.value != value:
            return head
    p.value = p.next.value
    if p.next == head:
        head = p
    p.next = p.next.next
    return head
    pass
```

the code is not giving answer for the case I have only one element and I deleted it so, the resultant code should be an empty set

For e.g.,

```
check_deletion([1], 1, [])
check_deletion([], 1, [])
```

Can anyone help me out.

Comment: What is it giving you as output exactly?

Comment: it points back again to itself and the same value is in the list.please help me out of this @aruisdante

Comment: It's because you copy the value of next before checking if next is head and current is head. I.E. you need a special case for a size 1 list where you remove the last element.

Comment: how do i write that can you give me an example to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix it by adding an additional clause to your `return none` statement:

```
 if p == None or (p.value == value and p.next = p):
    return None
```